# How to pass a JSON file from the back-end to the front-end

Tags: json, angular, spring

I have a JSON file with a list of products in my back-end ( Spring ). I want to be able to pass the content to the front-end ( in Angular ).

I have a JSON file in an assets folder in my front-end made with angular.
This is the JSON file:

```
    [ {
        "brand": "",
        "category": {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "hand held"
        },
        "description": "New D131 Scanner complete",
        "hidden": false,
        "id": 10,
        "image": null,
        "productNumber": "E14NO1617",
        "quantity":1
      },
      {
        "brand": "",
        "category": {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "hand held"
        },
        "description": "New D132 Scanner complete",
        "hidden": false,
        "id": 10,
        "image": null,
        "productNumber": "E14NO1617",
        "quantity":1
      },
      {
        "brand": "",
        "category": {
          "id": 50,
          "name": "card reader"
        },
        "description": "USB,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": 26,
        "image": null,
        "productNumber": "ST-1044UB",
        "quantity": 1
      }
      ]
```

I then display the objects ( products in my case ) on a table with the following function in the service:

```
    getTemplates() : Promise<Product[]> {
      return this.http.get<Product[]>("http://localhost:4200/assets/BirdyProducts.json")
        .toPromise();
    }
```

This works exactly like I want it to be displayed,
But I don't want to store the the JSON in my front-end assets folder.
I want it to be in my back-end in a resources folder and send the file with a rest-controller and still get the same result.

I tried a lot with Objectmapper, JSONObjects,... but did not find a solution.

Comment: You can store the JSON and create an API to return the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class ExampleController {
    @GetMapping("/BirdyProducts")
    public InputStreamResource getJsonFile() throws IOException {
        return new InputStreamResource(new ClassPathResource("/assets/BirdyProducts.json").getInputStream());
    }
}
```

When I request for http://localhost:8080/BirdyProducts I get the content of the file.

The file is in the `\src\main\resources\assets` folder on the backend side.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
public class BirdyProductsController {

    @RequestMapping(
      value = "/birdyProducts", 
      method = RequestMethod.GET, 
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )

    String getBirdyProducts() {
        return "json/BirdyProducts.json";
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Path to JSON file: \src\main\resources\static\json\BirdyProducts.json